# Will my baked potatoes be ok cooked longer at a low temp?

Tags: baking, potatoes

I am slow cooking a roast at 275 for 3 1/2 hours and want baked potatoes also. Will my potatoes be ok if I cook them at 275 for 2 or 3 hours? Maybe if I start them in the microwave for a few minutes and then 275 for a couple of hours?

Answer (score 1):

They should be perfectly fine if cooked for that long. If you are still uncertain then you can try adding some liquid to the pan to help boil the potatoes.